# How do I load the two stages of a saved Faster R-CNN separately in TF Object Detection 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

I trained a [Faster R-CNN](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/fc8466973fa42950b345f6fe1297f91ad0e15cc1/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L290) from the [TF Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and saved it using [`export_inference_graph.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/export_inference_graph.py). I have the following directory structure:

```
weights
|-checkpoint
|-frozen_inference_graph.pb
|-model.ckpt-data-00000-of-00001
|-model.ckpt.index
|-model.ckpt.meta
|-pipeline.config
|-saved_model
|--saved_model.pb
|--variables
```

I would like to load the first and second stages of the model separately. That is, I would like the following two models:

1. A model containing each variable in the scope `FirstStageFeatureExtractor` which accepts an image (or serialized `tf.data.Example`) as input, and outputs the feature map and RPN proposals.
2. A model containing each variable in the scopes `SecondStageFeatureExtractor` and `SecondStageBoxPredictor` which accepts a feature map and RPN proposals as input, and outputs the bounding box predictions and scores.

I basically want to be able to call [_predict_first_stage](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/fc8466973fa42950b345f6fe1297f91ad0e15cc1/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L869) and [_predict_second_stage](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/fc8466973fa42950b345f6fe1297f91ad0e15cc1/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py#L961) separately on my input data.

Currently, I only know how to load the entire model:

```
model = tf.saved_model.load("weights/saved_model")
model = model.signatures["serving_default"]
```

EDIT 6/7/2020:
For Model 1, I may be able to extract `detection_features` as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170336/tf-object-detection-api-extract-feature-vector-for-each-detection-bbox), but I'm still not sure about Model 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more difficult when Object Detection was only compatible with TF1, but is now pretty simple in TF2. There's a good example in [this colab.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/inference_tf2_colab.ipynb)

```
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util

# Set path names
model_name = 'centernet_hg104_512x512_kpts_coco17_tpu-32'
pipeline_config = os.path.join('models/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/',
                                model_name + '.config')
model_dir = 'models/research/object_detection/test_data/checkpoint/'

# Load pipeline config and build a detection model
configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(pipeline_config)
model_config = configs['model']
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=model_config, 
                                     is_training=False)

# Restore checkpoint
ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(
      model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(model_dir, 'ckpt-0')).expect_partial()
```

From here one can call `detection_model.predict()` and associated methods such as `_predict_first_stage` and `_predict_second_stage`.